# Can you make a <input type="text"> element have a size shorter than 1?

Tags: html

I have an `<input>` that I want to be smaller than `size="1"` but I do not know how to make it smaller. Is it possible to do this?

I tried using fractions and decimals but neither worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can assign it a pixel width instead:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 4px">
```

Comment: I have a situation where it appears my input tag refuses to go less than 13px. Any thoughts?

Comment: @aturc my guess would be font size... can you create a live example in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 5):

[For `type="text"`, no](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-size-INPUT). At least, not using the `size` attribute:

> The width is given in pixels except when type attribute has the value "text" or "password". In that case, its value refers to the (integer) number of characters.